# Removing files matching a numeric range regular expression

Tags: bash, terminal, regex, rm

I have a folder which has many files. Some of the data files are labelled 1, 2, 3, ..., 300

I want to remove these data files using the terminal. How do I do this?

I want to do something like

```
rm some-regular-expression-giving-numbers-from-0--300
```

Comment: Are they just called `1`, `2`, etc. and do they all match an expression that gives numbers from 0 to 300, or are there any other elements in the filename? Can you give us a more concrete example, maybe with a directory listing?

Comment: Yes they are just called 1, 2, etc.

Answer (score 18):

You can try

```
rm some-files-with-numbers{0..300}
```

This will delete:

```
some-files-with-numbers0

some-files-with-numbers1

some-files-with-numbers2

...

some-files-with-numbers300
```

Answer (score 1):

I like superuser’s answer, but to add another possibility:

```
find . -regex './some-files-with-numbers[123]?[0-9]?[0-9]' -delete
```

Comment: What about `some-files-with-numbers301`?

Comment: @cYrus I am aware of the limitations :) My answer was more aimed at being an alternative to superuser’s one.